# Seeking Indian city points and village boundaries?

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries, india

I am looking for Indian city/village points and village/Taluk boundaries for India.

A perfect example what I am looking for is [here](http://hsdi.in:8080/geoserver/www/webgis/index.html) for the State of Haryan, produce by 
[Haryana Space Applications Centre](http://www.harsac.org/).

Till now I am little lost, can some body point me in right direction and share some sources from where I can get this data for commercial purpose.

Just for **update** for all who are following

I have found [here](http://www.surveyofindia.gov.in/pages/display/91-pricing-of-digital-products) that Survey of India has "Village Bdy.Database (#42)". This is exactly what i am looking but till today no response from them.

Any body have some idea how to purchase this layer from them.

Answer (score 2):

For administrative boundaries, look at [GADM database of Global Administrative Areas](http://www.gadm.org/country)
Select India, and choose "level 3".

Edit: here's a screen grab of the resulting KML file, looks like it matches the link you provided, but GADM has it for the whole country.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am aware of GADM and in ind_adm3 there are only 2299 Taluk but this list (http://www.indiacodebank.com/taluks/1) shows some other figures.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the [Census India web site](http://www.censusindia.gov.in) which provides various admin boundary maps.

For some states it is down to the level of villages where as most states have it up to Taluka (Tehsil, subdistrict) level.