# Seeking shapefiles for Indian Metros?

Tags: shapefile, data, maps, india

I am looking for shapefiles with ward boundaries for the following Indian cities: Mumbai (electoral wards), Hyderabad, Ahmedabad, Surat and Kolkata.

Does anyone has them or know where I can get them from?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58574/finding-municipal-level-administrative-boundary-data-for-india might help, as well as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62976/indian-city-points-and-village-boundaries.